# Toggle Buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

I am quite new to flutter so if this question feels trivial or not required, I apologize!!

I have a Toggle widget which holds a Row widget with 5 children, but I have also added 4 SizedBox to create the difference between the 5 Container widgets.

I want the 5 containers to show a different colour when clicked and store an int value associated with them.

I followed the official doc and the Youtube video along with it but couldn't get far. **Here is my code:**

```
ToggleButtons(
                            isSelected: <bool>[true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                            children: <Widget>[
                              GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                    height: 85,
                                    width: 85,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: _colour,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('images/happy_icon.png'),
                                        width: 75,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    remind = 1;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
// ... 3 more widgets like these

GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                    height: 85,
                                    width: 85,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: _colour,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('images/sad.png'),
                                        width: 75,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    remind = 5;
                                  });
                                },
                              )
selectedColor: _selectedColour,
                            onPressed: (int index) {
                              setState(() {
                                for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
                                  if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                    isSelected[buttonIndex] = !isSelected[buttonIndex];
                                  } else {
                                    isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                                  }
                                }
                              });
                            },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using just a `Column` with children which are the buttons wrapped in a `GestureDetector` then `onTap()` set the state of the color, then save the integer.

Example:

```
          Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  associatedInt = 1;
                  setState(() {
                    if(containerColor == Colors.white)
                      containerColor = Colors.blue;
                    else
                      containerColor = Colors.white;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: containerColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I used only one child but you can use more. Hope this helped.

Comment: oh yeahh, that's a creative approach to it, I will try it and get back to you! thanks!!